# Kindle Fire HD Developer Options

Tags: android, debugging, kindle-fire

I have been trying to sort out how to enable "Developer Options" (GPU usage, Layout Bounds, Pointer Location etc) for the Kindle Fire HD. I can't seem to find any posts about how to do it, or if the device even supports it.

Clicking on the System Version entry in settings doesn't do anything (as I'm certain that would be the bulk of answers I get)

So this is really a two part question..

Is it even possible to enable Developer Options, and if you can, how?

Comment: I am not looking to Enable ADB. For more info on "Developer Options) see http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html (On-Device Developer Options)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developer Options are possible to turn on for this device by going to settings, device options, tap serial number 7 times.

Then scroll down to the bottom of device options and click on the newly-visible Developer Options.

Comment: I'm not sure why I was downvoted, but developer options were not possible to be enabled when this question was posted!

Comment: At least for me, it was not possible because there was a pending update waiting for a reboot. As soon as I rebooted, it worked just fine.

Comment: Fire HD 8 (bought in 2019) - yes

Comment: Device will often need a reboot prior to this CORRECT ANSWER working. There is no need to hold the serial number down as of April 2020.

Comment: I have a Fire HD10 11th generation and this worked. Once back out of "About Fire Tablet" developer options where showing as a choice under "Device Options".

Answer (score 7):

Click on the kindle serial number and hold it like you are going to copy and paste. A message will appear that you are four steps from being a developer. Then just click it and hold three more times. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The message appears at the bottom of the screen after you release the serial number. I had to click and hold for about 4 seconds and then release to see the first message and repeat 3 more times. Each time gave me a message.

Comment: This is no longer how this works as of April 2020. The answer that is marked correct from UuDdLrLrSs is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Ldpets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934445/3195477) is correct.

Here's the detailed steps:

- Open Settings
- Open Device Options
- Tap the Serial number seven times
- Swipe to the bottom of the Device Options menu
- Developer Options should be the last item

Answer (score 1):

I have a Kindle Fire HD. The way I did it was to:

1. Open "Settings"
2. Select "Security"
3. Now you should see the "Enable ADB" with a description "Enables Kindle developers to debug over USB". Click "On".

If you click on the "Enable ADB", a message will show and it says "ADB is an advanced feature for developers which enables access to all applications and data on your Kindle. Your Kindle and personal data are not secure when ADB is enabled."

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble, make sure you're logged into your tablet under the main profile/user account. I was trying under a secondary profile/user account I created and tapping the serial 7 times did nothing until I switched back to the main one.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Device > Enable ADB